# Downstream DAG tasks don't run when schedule_interval=None

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've got a DAG configured with its `schedule_interval` argument set to `None`. When I manually trigger the DAG using the **Trigger Dag** button in the Airflow UI, it runs the first task successfully, but the downstream tasks never start; their states are all set to *null*.
[image]

The `airflow_scheduler` is running, and when I set the `schedule_interval` arg to something other than None, everything runs just fine. The `start_date` is set to a date several months back, and the DAG is not paused.

I'm guessing that the schedule being set to None is interfering with the downstream tasks starting, but I haven't seen anything in the Airflow docs that speak to this specific scenario. Is there an argument or setting that I'm missing that would allow those downstream tasks to run?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were experimenting with different schedule intervals while keeping `dag_id` unchanged. In [Common Pitfalls](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62694614) it is explicitly mentioned:

> - When needing to change your start_date and schedule interval, change the name of the dag (a.k.a. dag_id) - I follow the convention: my_dag_v1, my_dag_v2, my_dag_v3, my_dag_v4, etc...
> - Changing schedule interval always requires changing the dag_id, because previously run TaskInstances will not align with the new schedule interval

So, to make sure that you make a fresh start with a new schedule interval follow these steps:

1. Stop the scheduler and the webserver.
2. Change the schedule interval to `None` **and** `dag_id` to some new ID.
3. Start the scheduler and the webserver.
4. Try manually triggering the DAG.

Comment: I just tried all of those steps, but I'm still still seeing the same behavior; the first task completes successfully, but none of the others start. Odd.

Comment: @knoll It's hard to say without seeing the actual code.

Comment: @knoll did you try changing the DAG id?

Comment: @Binoy, yes. I iterated the dag_id by one as noted in the common pitfalls documentation.